Typescript get WriteableKeys from other types
I'm trying to write a type that gets the type of all non-readOnly properties in a type.
Then I found one that looks like this:
type IfEquals<X, Y, A = X, B = never> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2 ? A : B
type WriteableKeys<T> = {
   [K in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ [Q in K]: T[K] }, { -readonly [Q in K]: T[K] }, K>
}[keyof T]
type R = WriteableKeys<{ readonly a: number; b: string }> // 'b'

I don't understand why it returns 'b' not 'b' | never .
When I try to delete [keyof T] in WriteableKeys, I get {readonly a: never; b: 'b'}, which is understandable, but when added with [keyof T], the result is so strange that I couldn't write code like this on my own without trying to understand it

• Your question, as asked, is something like "why do I get X instead of X | never?" and has nothing to do with "writeable keys" per se. • Note that X | never is identical to X.  The never type is absorbed in unions. See other q/a for more information.
